# Assigning tasks to workers - How many ways to do it?

Tags: combinatorics

Below is a problem I did. I would like somebody to check it for me.

Problem:

A manager needs four tasks of type A done. He also needs two tasks of type B done. He has 10 employees. The manager wants to assign one task each to six employees. This means that four employees will not get a task. How many ways can he assign the six tasks be assigned?
Answer:
Let $c$ be the number we are looking for.
\begin{align*}
c &= { 10 \choose 2}{10 \choose 4} \\
{ 10 \choose 2} &= \frac{10(9)}{2} = 45 \\
{ 10 \choose 6} &= \frac{10(9)(8)(7)} {4(3)(2)} = \frac{10(9)(7)}{3} = 10(30(7) = 210 \\
c &= 45(210) \\
c &= 9450
\end{align*}

Here is my second attempt at solving the problem:

\begin{align*}
c &= { 10 \choose 2}{8 \choose 4} \\
{ 10 \choose 2} &= \frac{10(9)}{2} = 45 \\
{ 8 \choose 4} &= \frac{8(7)(6)(5)} {4(3)(2)} = \frac{7(6)(5)}{3} = 70 \\
c &= 45(70) \\
c &= 3150
\end{align*}

I believe I have it right now. Could somebody confirm that I do?

Comment: After choosing $2$ from $10$, how many are left for the choice of $4$?

Comment: Suppose that the employees are $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$, and $j$. Your calculation includes the possibility, for instance, that he chooses $a$ and $b$ for the type B tasks and $a,b,c$, and $d$ for the type A tasks. Now $a$ and $b$ are doing two tasks each.

Comment: @quasi There would be 8 left? I think you are saying my answer is wrong. I am thinking my answer is wrong.

Comment: @Bob: Right, $8$ left, so after choosing $2$ from $10$, the next choice is $4$ from $8$.

Comment: @Bob Although that $3150$ is the correct answer can be verified by [direct counting](https://tio.run/##RYxBCoMwEEX3nmJ2k4CU2HZRBBfakxRN6EDMhHFcSOnZ0yyE7h78918@9M3p9shSCq2ZRYHUizLHrQnCK8wco5@VOG1wGk/eU5WaLJTUbPtqOggsQEDpf79k4WWf1eA4OWzFZ//SoXMWKMBCdTg7hqwdhg@O2N9bnLC/tugqf60t5Qc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the significance of two types of tasks? If one worker can be assigned at most 1 job, the total number of allocations is $\binom{10}{6}$. If for some reason you want to separate workers into groups performing each type of task it is $\binom{10}{2} \binom{8}{4}$